# Using a file DSN with JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, dsn

I can happily connect to a System DSN using JDBC:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:SysDSN");
```

If I try and use a File DSN however I get an error:
    `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

Using:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:FileDSN");
```

I've tried specifying a path to the File DSN and still get no joy.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using an DSN-less connection URL, as shown here:

[Creating a DSN-less connection for MS Access within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016730/creating-a-dsn-less-connection-for-ms-access-within-java)

You won't have to create a DSN that way.

PS - You *did* create the data source before you tried it your way, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, the File DSN was created. Didn't really want to go down the DSN-less route for various reasons. Would really like to see an example of a file DSN working in Java.

Comment: Is the file visible to your machine?  Are you running on a 64-bit OS?  If yes, I'm afraid you're out of luck - there is no JDBC-ODBC bridge driver for 64 bit machines.

Comment: Not on 64-bit, and the file is very much visible as it is on the machine I'm running the code on.

Comment: *Still* no solution?  I'd find something else besides Access that has a Type IV JDBC driver and get on with it.