# creating jdbc odbc connection without creating the DSN in MS ACCESS

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am trying to make the connection between java and ms access database. I want to make the connection without creating the DSN. I am using the following code but it is throwing the exception "Data source name not found exception "

```
     try
     { 
     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access
     Driver(*.mdb)}; dbq=d:/newfolder/db11.mdb");
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
    {
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: [already answered here, this may help you ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5016979/1655086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be like this:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=/db.accdb");
```

Comment: Dear Alvin using the same command but its giving the Exception as Data source name not found exception.

Comment: Is the database file located at your project path?

Comment: i can allocate it but now its located somewhere else

Comment: Dear the problem start from Driver= because my program considers it as  dsn name

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and tried many of the suggestions here and on various forums. Finally, I discovered a snippet from one place which led to success connecting and also explains why many of these posts do not work. See http://www.coderanch.com/t/295299/JDBC/databases/jdbc-odbc-DSN-connection-MS

The issue is that there must be a semicolon after the colon at the end of odbc as in jdbc:odbc:;Driver=                 .  This made sense after reading the Oracle documentation on the JdbcOdbc bridge which states that the syntax is jdbc:odbc:dsn; attributes....... Since we are not supplying a DSN, then we need to end with ; before adding attributes.

I am showing below the tests I ran with different connection strings on a Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit machine:

```
        driver= (Driver)Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
        //jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=  does lookup to ODBC.ini to find matching driver


            try {
            connstr= "jdbc:odbc:;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + fileURI;  //64 bit ?? (*.mdb,*.accdb)  
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, "", ""); 
            stmt= conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        try {
            connstr= "jdbc:odbc:;Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + fileURI;  //64 bit ?? (*.mdb,*.accdb)  
            conn1= DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, "", ""); 
            stmt1= conn1.createStatement();
            dbmeta1=conn1.getMetaData();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        try {
            connstr= "jdbc:odbc:MS Access Database;DBQ=" + fileURI;  //64 bit ?? (*.mdb,*.accdb)  
            conn2= DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, "", ""); 
            stmt2= conn2.createStatement();
            dbmeta2=conn2.getMetaData();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        try {
            connstr= "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + fileURI;  //64 bit ?? (*.mdb,*.accdb)  
            conn3= DriverManager.getConnection(connstr, "", ""); 
            stmt3= conn3.createStatement();
            dbmeta3=conn3.getMetaData();
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
```

stmt1 and stmt3 are null since the connections are null. stmt and stmt2 work. stmt2 uses a connection string I found in the documentation for IBM Tivoli. It works because "MS Access Database" is a valid title in the ODBC registry as a User DSN on my computer.

Comment: Note that this will cease to work upon upgrade to Java 8, as the Sun/Oracle JDK-bundled JDBC-ODBC Bridge has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC connection string start with `jdbc:` like:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=d:\\newfolder\\db11.mdb
```

Comment: using the same command but giving the exception Data source name not found Exception

Comment: @Adeshsingh : do you have db11 at the specified location and check the extension whether it is mdb

Comment: ya i have the database on the same location and the error is related to DSN not the database location please help i m stuck badly here.

Comment: @Adeshsingh : are you sure that the db extension is mdb and not accdb?