# How set a path in java databank ODBC

Tags: java, database, odbc

I want to insert the values in the BDLivros.mdb that is in C:/PLB/ but when I test the code below it says that isn't possible do find the path to BDLivros

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 try
 {
 String url = "jdbc:odbc:aulajava";
 String usuario = "";
 String senha = "";
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 Connection con;
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,senha);
 Statement st = con.createStatement();
 String x = "INSERT INTO C:\\PLB\\BDLivros (cd_prod, ds_prod,vl_prod, qt_pesoprod) VALUES (7,3,4.5,300)";

 st.executeUpdate(x);

 x = "INSERT INTO C:\\PLB\\BDLivros (cd_prod, ds_prod, vl_prod,qt_pesoprod) VALUES (8,3,1.5,100)";

 st.executeUpdate(x);
 con.close();
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 System.out.println("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INSERT SQL should have the name of the table.  Once you open the database connection, the path to the file is irrelevant.

Your connection URL isn't what I'd recommend.  Better to use a [DSN-less database connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016730/creating-a-dsn-less-connection-for-ms-access-within-java) string.

There's a lot not to like about your code:

1. You don't close resources.
2. You don't use PreparedStatement
3. You don't print the complete stack trace in catch block.
4. You put all the code in the main method; no reusable.